# Conservation of Angular Momentum...or not?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, orbital-motion, simulations

This is my first post on physics stack exchange, but I thought the question was more appropriate than on that of math.stack. I'm currently designing a crude model of the sun-earth orbit (which I have done to a fairly decent accuracy) and want to include the impact of a comet; considering the bodies are rigid to begin with. The conclusion of the project will be to analyze the effects of the comet impact on earths motion and the probabilistic effects on life the given perturbation would have. Again I would like to stress this is a crude model and is more a demonstration of my understanding of numerical integration techniques, computational mathematics, and calculus in general.

I want the collision to be elastic (to begin with) and I want to produce a resultant, and therefore, initial velocity from the impact. Can I use the conservation of angular momentum to do this? At first I used conservation of energy but this didn't seem like the right approach. I have been reading about conservation of angular momentum for a couple of days and I cant seem to find anything that suits my desires.

If anybody with a background on this could either give me advice, or tell me if this question is too soft for the site (i know what math.stack is like) that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Comets don't rebound, so the choice of elasticity seems incorrect.  Also, the effects on life are not based on the long-term changes in earth's momentum, but on the (shorter-term) energy release.  Calculating momentum changes could be done, but it seems almost irrelevant.  Earth's mass is larger than most comets by a factor of more than $10^{10}kg$

Comment: It wasn't so much the earth's momentum I was concerned with, but the perturbation of the earth's orbit around the sun, particularly the effect a reduced/increased velocity would have with respect to the earth's position in known habitable zones. I know comets don't rebound that's why I stated the model was crude. I'm treating all of these body's as rigid particles colliding. I guess the main question I'm posing is how can form an equation given two masses, two velocities, and derive a resultant velocity. Momentum seemed like a logical construction, like I said I'm no physicist.

Comment: You appear to be looking for "inelastic momentum conservation formula".

Comment: Thank you for your input BowlOfRed I know the question may seem elementary, and my use of the word comet was probably used a bit lightly. I meant any body of significant size/velocity maybe meteor is the correct terminology.

Comment: May I suggest you change your model to, say, a 1-kg steel ball in orbit, perturbed by a high-velocity 0.1 g object?  That will let you avoid the fact that a meteor hitting the earth will be demolished, and the earth itself reshaped if the meteor is large enough. Two small steel objects could in fact have an elastic collision.

Comment: This is a neat idea indeed! The only problem is further analysis of the object and the effects of its resultant perturbations. The only reason I chose the earth-sun system was so I could do some analysis on habitable zones after implementing my model. I am completely aware any impact great enough to cause drastic changes to habitable zones would completely destroy earth itself, but this is an assumption I would have to include. I need something more to come out of the project than just the collision of two objects and their resultant orbits.

Comment: yes, momentum is always conserved, you can crudely model model the collision as purely inelastic, so that the comet (and its potential debris) stays attached to the planet

Comment: You do not need to destroy the planet, instead of a direct impact you could model close encounters that modify the orbit, and calculate how many average encounters do you need to move the orbit from an initial to a final orbit outside your habitable range.

Comment: That's also a smart idea Bruce, I will consider all of this. I did (crudely) implement the model as purely inelastic as you so stated and it gives a variety of fairly interesting results albeit at high velocity impacts. One final question to contributors of this post: I've been using Verlet Integration as I've read this has advantages over RK4 (or in matlabs case ode45) do you think this is sufficient enough an integration method, should I use RK4 instead? If you are not well versed in these methods do not worry.